# My legs are oriented to a point when i animate it (lego character)

Tags: animation

If you could help me with my lego star wars animation.
When i import a lego character in blender and rig it (with epicfigrig), the two feet are connected by dotted lines to a cross.
And when i animate the feet (when i do about 2 steps) the feet are not doing what i want and start to orienting themselves to the cross (with the same dotted lines at the legs). I dont have my pc with me
but i can illustrate it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is a image of my problem.
As you can see the legs are doing strange things